# Git: i forgot to branch

Tags: git

I'm new to Git, and not sure how to proceed with this.  Here's my use case:

I had a stable version of the code, all checked in on my desktop and pushed to my remote repo.  Then i did a pull from the remote repo to my laptop and added features and destabilized the code.  ( but i **didn't** do a branch first ).

Now i'm back on my desktop.  I like the snapshot i have here.  I want to tag it version 1.0.  But i'm out of sync with the remote repo.  What steps would you guys recommend?  The snapshot on my laptop is important too obviously but not yet stable.

thx,
matt

Comment: Have you pushed from your laptop to your remote repo yet?

Comment: Have you commited your changes already? If not you can make a new branch now and commit to the new branch.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  The problem is i already pushed from the laptop to the remote repo.  I'll review the answers below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag the current HEAD on your desktop and then pull from the remote repository. Then push the tags back. What's the problem with that? The situation will be

A - B - C - D(v1.0) - E - F (master)

where E and F are unstable changes that you made on your laptop and pushed back to the remote repository.

Comment: Worked great, the only wrinkle was `git push` doesn't include tags by default, you need to include the `--tags` flag

Answer (score 10):

Create a branch where you are, but stay on master:

```
git branch my-cool-feature
```

Then reset master to the state on the remote:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Finally put a tag on you feature branch:

```
git tag 1.0 my-cool-feature
```

Comment: Thanks for making this easy. Perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a branch of an arbitrary patchset.

git branch someBranch 46744feg

Comment: "patchset" is not a git term as far as I know. It's called a commit here.

Comment: sorry it is used in gerrit, sometimes the borders get blurry.